# how to launch windows phone 8 app from php code(browser)?

Tags: php, windows-phone-8

I am programming an Windows Phone 8 App. The User has to validate his e-mail-address by klicking on a link provided in an email. If this link is opened on a windows phone, it should be possible to directly launch the windows phone 8 app. The part where a php-site openes and tells you "your email address is now validated", should be skiped.

How is it possible to launch the app from this link? Or do I have to open the php-site anyway? Can I maybe provide a Link in the php-site that directly opens the App?

Thanks for help

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page shows some good ways to accomplish what you're asking about:

[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Edit: Adding PHP code

```
header('Location: contoso:NewProducts');
```

It could be as simple as rendering a link with the proper protocol and token.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I managed to register the URI in the App, but how do I call this URI from php? 
I have tried something like this: openURI("contoso:NewProducts");
But it is a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function openURI()"

Comment: I would try 

header("Location: contoso:NewProducts");

but make sure you haven't sent out any other output before this command.